# No-IP on Linux: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: linux, fedora, dynamic-dns

I want to setup a small home server using **Fedora 17 (32 Bit)** and **No-ip** because I have a Dynamic IP adress,

This is what am I doing:

**1) I create a Host on No-ip:**

[image: image description]

**2) I setup No-ip on my fedora box:**

```
su -
yum install noip
noip2 -C
chkconfig noip --add
chkconfig --levels 35 noip on
```

*NOTE: My no-ip config file it's located at: /etc/no-ip2.conf*

Reboot and verify it is running:

```
su -
service noip status
chkconfig --list | grep noip
host myserver.servebeer.com
```

(it actually points to my public IP adress)

**3) Open Ports on the fedora's firewall:**

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

**4) Unlock No-IP on iptables:**

```
su -
iptables -A INPUT -s dynupdate.no-ip.com -p tcp --sport 8243 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d dynupdate.no-ip.com -p tcp --dport 8243 -j ACCEPT
service iptables stop
service iptables start
service noip stop
service noip start
service noip status
```

**5) Port Fowarding on the router:**

[image: image description]

(I get the private IP adress from **ifconfig**)

**6) Verify with zenmap, telnet & ping**

[image: image description]

*NOTE: Here we have an interesting situation: Only the 80 TCP port seems to be open, the other two (111, 8243) are closed, even when they are unlocked on the firewall and forwarded on the router.*

[image: image description]

PING fails, but as far as I know this is kinda normal right? 'cause ping isn't a DNS test mechanism... Correct me if I'm wrong please:

[image: image description]

**Additional info:**

I have an **Apache/PHP** setup, so if I go to `**http://127.0.0.1/test.php**` I see my test.php page, but if I go to **http://myserver.servebeer.com** or **http://myserver.servebeer.com/test.php** I can't see anything, the browser just tries and tries and then throws an error...

*P.S. SELinux is fully Disabled*

What am I doing wrong? Please Help me!

Comment: Does your ISP allow you to host your own server?  Don't assume they do.  In most cases, ISPs will not allow port 80 traffic in this manner.  For test purposes, try setting up your server using port 81 instead (or port 8080, or whatever you like), and when you attempt to connect to it from the outside, remember to add the :81 (or :8080 or whatever port you chose) to the end of the address.  See if that works.  You know.. http://myserver.servebeer.com:81 just as an example

Comment: When I configure no-ip, I must start a cron job to force the noip service every 5 hours ( http://www.fclose.com/4677/how-to-install-noip2-on-linux/ ) -- to capture the latest dynamical IP.